# Not enough information to infer type variable T when finding button resource

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to create an array of buttons that are in an XML file. The error occurs on this line in my project:

```kotlin
val buttons = arrayOf(findViewById(R.id.button0))
```

I tried using `kotlin-android-extensions` in my `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

But that did not fix the error.

Comment: Don’t use Kotlin-Android-extensions. It is obsolete and won’t work in modern Kotlin. You need to specify the type of your view you are finding, such as `findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)`.